# Custom crontab does not work (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, cron

I created file crontab.custom with:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/username/data/www/run.sh
```

And `run.sh` contains:

```
php script.php
```

After this I run this command `crontab crontab.custom`.

Now `crontab -l` returns my task.

I restarted cron with `/etc/rc.d/cron restart`, but `script.php` is not called. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Log files should mention cron job failures. Check them. (No idea exactly which, never used FreeBSD.)

Comment: The output of your cron job is send as a mail to the user who has added the cron job. So just open a console and type `mail` and go through the messages.

Comment: output of `mail`: `no mail for username`

Comment: Is /home/username/data/www/run.sh set executable? (you may need to do a `chmod u+x /home/username/data/www/run.sh`)

Comment: yes, it is, i ran `chmod 777`..

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your `$PATH` is not set. When you try to execute `php` in your shell, in reality, it looks up the absolute destination of `php` from your `$PATH`, which is a list of directories from which to locate executables. This is set in your environment, but cron doesn't share that environment (in fact, it probably has an empty or unset `$PATH`). There are a few solutions (from best to worst):

- Set `$PATH` in your crontab by adding something like this to the top of it:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

- Use the full path to the `php` executable in the script (this is bad, the user should be able to override the PATH in the environment to use different binaries if they want);
- Set `$PATH` explicitly in your script (bad for the same reason).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I have: `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/1 * * * * /home/username/data/www/run.sh`
But nothing changed..

Comment: @Chris:  your 2nd solution being "bad" is arguable. You might want to use a specific version/installation of php instead of the one provided by $PATH.

Comment: @Ouki That's exactly the reason why it is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Append the following lines on the top of your shell script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH
```

then put the cron job using

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Unfortunately no gain

Answer (score 1):

Issues with crontab files tend to be related with a different environment when run under cron. As you haven't provided the file `run.sh`, here are some troubleshooting tips:

1. As yourself, type `/home/username/data/www/run.sh` on the command-line and make sure that it works
2. Make sure that all paths are explicitly set as full paths in your script
3. Confirm that you have added the data in the correct place - `crontab -e` lets you edit your crontab file
4. Make sure that you're allowed to use cron. Your username must be in the `/var/cron/allow` file and not be in the `/var/cron/deny` file
5. Check the output of /var/log/cron